# ItemClick Event in a flex Combobox

Tags: apache-flex, events, combobox, onitemclicklistener

Does anyone know, is there any way to catch ItemClick Event in a Flex ComboBox (or anything similar). Maybe there's any trick .. :) I do realize, that I can customize it, but this not suits my case.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Nice nick, little aerial ;) Why do you need itemClick? Maybe the original problem has another solution.

Comment: Thanks :) Maybe you're right .. but I'm still curious in getting this to work. So the only solution is customization?

Comment: What kind of combo box do you use? MX or Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in `mx:ComboBox` sources, the function, creating the dropdown list, is private, the listener to `ITEM_CLICK` is private and the list itself is also private:

```
private var _dropdown:ListBase;

private function getDropdown():ListBase
{
        // ...

        _dropdown = dropdownFactory.newInstance();

        // ...

        _dropdown.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK, dropdown_itemClickHandler);

        // ....
}

private function dropdown_itemClickHandler(event:ListEvent):void
{
    if (_showingDropdown)
    {
        close();
    }
}
```

So you can not even extend `ComboBox`.

The only public thing is `dropdownFactory`, which theoretically can be overriden to somehow register the created dropdown list or create extended list. But the problem I see is that `ComboBox` is not the parent of dropdown list - PopupManager is. This can make dispatching (bubble) events quite difficult.

Comment: Hmmm .. true, quite difficult. What if, say, have 2 components: ComboBox and List. Set the dropdownWidth of the Combo to 0. Place the List under it. And when user somehow tries to open a combo, show a List control (instead of dropDown). I just have doubts on .. is it dirty solution? I saw such thing in one of AutoComplete components.

Comment: IMHO, it's easier is to write own `ComboBox` with everything you need (с блэкджеком и шлюхами), which is partially copypasted from original. I've already written the editable one with filters and tree as dropdown - and I can't imagine, how I would patch and hack origonal `ComboBox` in order to achieve desired behavior.

Comment: Heh, true .. thanks for the explanations (доходчиво :Р). Failed with avoiding the customization .. off to write my Combo-Masterpiece :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following document will be helpful

[ItemClick event in flex List](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/05/14/detecting-an-item-click-event-on-a-spark-list-control-in-flex-4/)

Comment: Thanks, the document is really helpful, but I need this event in a ComboBox :)

Comment: Uhm .. one idea about ItemClick and List ... is replacing a ComboBox's dropdown with a List is this a good idea, or an epic fail? :)

Comment: The dropdown in `ComboBox` is already a `List`: `private var _dropdownFactory:IFactory = new ClassFactory(List);`

Comment: @Antenka What moropus saying is correct the combobox, dropdown are extended from the listbase only. try that for the combo i think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. I just want a spark dropdownlist with itemClick event and without itemselect option (don't show selected item label on button)

```
[Event(name="itemClick", type="mx.events.ItemClickEvent")]

public class ItemClickDropDownList extends DropDownList
{

    public function ItemClickDropDownList()
    {
        super();
    }

    override public function closeDropDown(commit:Boolean):void
    {
        super.closeDropDown(commit);

        var e:ItemClickEvent = new ItemClickEvent(ItemClickEvent.ITEM_CLICK, true);
        e.item = this.selectedItem;
        e.index = this.selectedIndex;
        dispatchEvent(e);

        //Deselect item
        this.selectedIndex = -1;
    }
```