# click events of combobox in flex

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, actionlistener, mouseclick-event

I found that in flex, combobox has 3 events: open, close, change
[combobox events example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_5.html)

Let's say I selected A in my combo box. Then I might do 2 things:

- I open combobox and click A option again
- I open combobox and close it by clicking somewhere else (without clicking A option)

There is no selection change in either of the case above. And they both have open and close involved. So if I want these 2 actions have different behaviors, I can't programmatically distinguish them....
Is it possible to have a click event on combobox or combobox options?? I am using a data provider for my combobox...

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

The [ComboBox events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html#eventSummary) do have a [click](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3aclick) event defined, although it is inherited.

Unless the ComboBox has a click event listener and calls preventDefault() to prevent the event from bubbling, you should be able to listen for the click event on a ComboBox without any issues.

Comment: Yes, ComboBox has a click event. But only a click event on a item of the combobox will solve my problem.... I found this post very similar to my problem, but doesn't seem to be a solution...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267982/itemclick-event-in-a-flex-combobox

Comment: If you were using the Spark ComboBox/DropDownList you should be able to add an event listener directly onto the drop down.